# How to use a function from another .c file?

Tags: c, function, makefile, compilation, definition

I'm using RTKLIB (it is not important), and inside a directory there are multiple .c files:

```
rtcm.c
rtmc2.c
rtcm3.c

etc. etc.
```

Inside the same directory, I created a `main.c` file, where the program is executed.
Inside `main.c` I call different functions that are defined in the different .c files.

There is only one `.h` file, which is `rtklib.h`, inside which, there are only struct definitions (there are not the declarations of the functions inside the other .c files).

How can I call, inside the main.c file, a function defined inside the `rtcm.c` file, for example?

How can I create a makefile that allows me to include all the `.c` file in when I compile?

Comment: These are very different questions. One is how to use functions in other files, the other is how to build everything with `make`. On SO there is a "one-question" guideline. Therefore please decide which one you want to have answered and create another question for the remaining part.

Comment: I would like to know how to compile all .c file in the directory in one time.

Comment: Then please edit the question and put the other stuff into a new post. But you might reconsider this as there is already an answer for the first part.

Comment: To help you with the building process, there's a whole slew of so called 'IDE'-Programs, which can help you with that. Popular ones include Visual Studio, Eclipse and Qt Creator. You may also want to look into cross-platform systems like for example CMake, because otherwise the Makefiles will be different for each system.

Comment: If RTKLIB is really a decent library, it should provide a header file with the public functions as prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the prototype of the function you want to export. Usually you would do that in the corresponding .h file.

A prototype mirrors the declaration of the function, just without the braces. So the prototype of `int someFunction(int parameter) {}` is, in fact, `int someFunction(int parameter);`.

Simply write the header of your function to your header file (or the .c file you want to use it in) and you're good.

Example:

`rtcm.c:`

```
int myFunction(int parameter1)
{
    //Does something
}
```

`rtcm.h:`

```
int myFunction(int parameter1);
```

`main.c:`

```
#include "rtcm.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myFunction(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do this at all. If you have a library, you should install it and link with the installed version.  If you really do want to build an executable without installing the library, you could use a GNUmakefile like:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))
    
main: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

For other versions of make, you can do something similar.  Let `make` use its default rules to build the object files.  All you need to do is list those object files on the final build line so the tool chain can build the executable.